# Recover iPhone backup file from SSD

Tags: iphone, backup, recovery

my MacBook Pro crashed I pulled out my 128G SSD and was able to connect and read it with my HD reader, I would like to locate the iPhone backup created previously I would like to locate it since I'm a PC user I'm not familiar with Mac OS I have both Mac & PC available to use 
Thanks in advance 
Joe
Hi, and thanks for the repay I was able to follow the steps provided but now it's telling me the folder "Library" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents. Thanks in advance –

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the repay I was able to follow the steps provided but now it's telling me the folder "Library" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can see the contents on the file system, the backups are located at `/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/` in relation to the root of the drive.

Heads up that the `Library` folder located in your user's directory is hidden. You can use shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in Finder to bring up the 'Go To' dialog so you can copy + paste that location to get to the file. Just be aware that if you're mounting the drive, you will need to append `/Volumes/DriveNameHere` to the beginning of the path.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the repay I was able to follow the steps provided but now it's telling me the folder "Library" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you logged into the same user that owns the library folder?

Comment: I was able to figure it out I really appropriate your quick response is it possible to walk me through the same step but it's a HD removed from a Windows PC the thing is I'm trying to recover a project I had saved on my iPhone at one point thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Your question says it's a hard drive removed from a MacBook Pro but you just said it's removed from a Windows PC. Which one is it?

Comment: I have 2 hard drives both computers crashed one Windows 7 pro and the other one is a Mac OS

Comment: Hi, Any luck on the steps?